# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind: 8080

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I am getting the `BindException` while starting the `jboss`
`java.net.BindException: Address already in use: 8080`

I have installed oracle 10g also in my machine. That is already using the port 8080. So, I have changed the port to 8083 in server.xml and tried to start the server it is giving me the same error

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind: 8083
```

Even i have tried with port 8009 i am getting the same error

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind: 8009
```

can any one help me to solve my problem and please explain me the reason also.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I have taken port number as 8089 and the issue get resolved... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use TCPView from microsoft

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

It gives the port number as well.